# Pandas: series of True or False in a column, select in another column the value when there is a True

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 price          High_cross
 0.00224311     False
 0.00224473     False
 0.00224422     False
 0.00224697     True
 0.00224899     True
 0.00224668     True
 0.00224967     True
 0.00224967     True
 0.00224983     True
 0.00225143     False
```

And what I need to do is loop on the column `High_cross`, when there is a `True` select the related `price` and compare it with the `price` the final `True` of the series. If the first price is below the second price, notify it in a new column `movement` by `True`. In this example it should look at something like that:

```
 price          High_cross  Movement
 0.00224311     False
 0.00224473     False
 0.00224422     False
 0.00224697     True         True
 0.00224899     True
 0.00224668     True
 0.00224967     True
 0.00224967     True
 0.00224983     True
 0.00225143     False
```

(because 0.00224983 is bigger than 0.00224697)!

I tried to play with the index but I am relatively stuck... any solution/idea? Thanks

Comment: @anky_91, thank you for the time you devote to me, but in the meantime my request changed... I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812841/pandas-select-the-values-price-based-on-two-different-column-conditions

Comment: Do you think you can have a look? many thanks

Comment: @anky_91, no worries! just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the below df:

```
       price  High_cross
0   0.002243       False
1   0.002245       False
2   0.002244       False
3   0.002247        True
4   0.002249        True
5   0.002247        True
6   0.002250        True
7   0.002250        True
8   0.002250        True
9   0.002251       False
10  0.002251        True
11  0.002250        True
```

Use:

```
df['identifier']=(df.High_cross.ne(df.High_cross.shift())).cumsum()
df['Movement']=df[df.High_cross].groupby('identifier')['price'].\
                       transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0]<x.iloc[-1])
print(df.drop('identifier',1))

       price  High_cross Movement
0   0.002243       False      NaN
1   0.002245       False      NaN
2   0.002244       False      NaN
3   0.002247        True     True
4   0.002249        True     True
5   0.002247        True     True
6   0.002250        True     True
7   0.002250        True     True
8   0.002250        True     True
9   0.002251       False      NaN
10  0.002251        True    False
11  0.002250        True    False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood completely what your goal is here. I assuemd:

1. Select price if respective High_Cross == True
2. Compare the price to the last price where High_Cross == True
3. Set respective Movement = True if current price < last price[High_Cross == True]

but the following code achieves what I think you want:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
X = np.random.choice(range(10), size=10, replace=True).tolist()
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
Y = [bool(y) for y in Y]

lst = []
movement = []
# Extract list of all true values
for price,cross in zip(X,Y):
    # Create list of tuples
    cross == True and lst.append((price,cross)) # If one liner avoiding the otherwise mandatory else statement

# Now do the work itself
for price,cross in zip(X,Y):
    movement.append(True) if cross == True and price > lst[-1][0] else movement.append(False)
    print("Price="+str(price)+", High_Cross="+str(cross)+", Movement="+str(movement[-1]))
```

Produces:

```
Price=3, High_Cross=True, Movement=True
Price=6, High_Cross=False, Movement=False
Price=6, High_Cross=True, Movement=True
Price=0, High_Cross=True, Movement=False
Price=9, High_Cross=True, Movement=True
Price=8, High_Cross=True, Movement=True
Price=4, High_Cross=False, Movement=False
Price=7, High_Cross=True, Movement=True
Price=0, High_Cross=False, Movement=False
Price=0, High_Cross=True, Movement=False
```

`