# Pandas: select the values price based on two different column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 price      direction   event           High_cross  movement
-------------------------------------------------------------
 0.00225246 down        0               False       False 
 0.00225506 up          crossing up     False       False   
 0.00225347 up          0               False       False   
 0.00225345 up          0               False       False   
 0.00225613 up          0               True        movement 
 0.00225506 up          0               True        True    
 0.00225345 up          0               False       movement
 0.00225235 down        0               False       False   
 0.00224500 down        crossing down   False       False   
 0.00225266 down        0               False       False
 0.00225246 up          crossing up     False       False
 0.00225506 up          0               False       False
 0.00225506 down        crossing down   False       False
```

This is a relative complexe request. When there is a `crossing up` in the `event` column, select the price which has as column's `High_cross` value `True` and `movement` value `movement` and compare it to the price row right before a `crossing down`. If the first price is smaller than the second price, notify it with a `True` statement in a new column. I have no idea on how to start! Any help? Please let me know if you need clarifications... thanks

Small correction, if there is no `movement` between one `crossing up` and a `crossing down`, the computation should not be done! thanks

In the example above it will be: select the line

```
price       direction   event   High_cross  movement
----------------------------------------------------
0.00225613  up          0       True        movement
```

because the column `High_cross` is `True` and `movement` has value `movement`, from this line take the price `0.00225613` and compares it with the price from a row right above a `crossing down` event so `0.00225235`

It should store the result like:

```
 price      direction   event           High_cross  movement  triggered
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 0.00225246 down        0               False       False 
 0.00225506 up          crossing up     False       False   
 0.00225347 up          0               False       False   
 0.00225345 up          0               False       False   
 0.00225613 up          0               True        movement 
 0.00225506 up          0               True        True    
 0.00225345 up          0               False       movement
 0.00225235 down        0               False       False   
 0.00224500 down        crossing down   False       False     True
 0.00225266 down        0               False       False
 0.00225246 up          crossing up     False       False
 0.00225506 up          0               False       False
 0.00225506 down        crossing down   False       False
```

Comment: Could you please add an example and be more specific in your question as it's not clear what you want to do?

Comment: @Albyorix, just added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

Improved with question update

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('precision', 8) # To see all decimals

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "price":[0.00225246,0.00225506,0.00225347,0.00225345,0.00225613,0.00225506,0.00225345,0.00225235,0.00224500,0.00225266,0.00225246,0.00225506,0.00225506],
    "direction":["down","up","up","up","up","up","up","down","down","down","up","up","down"],
    "event": [0,"crossing up",0,0,0,0,0,0,"crossing down",0,"crossing up",0,"crossing down"],
    "High_cross": [False,False,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],
    "movement": [False,False,False,False,"movement",True,"movement",False,False,False,False,False,False]
})

# Add result column
df['triggered'] = "No"

pre_row = []
match_price = None
match_price_2 = None
matched = False
start_search = False
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        pre_row = row
        continue
    if row["event"] == 'crossing up':
        start_search = True
    if start_search and row["High_cross"] == True and row["movement"] == 'movement':
        match_price = row["price"]
        matched = True
    if matched and row["event"] == 'crossing down':
        match_price_2 = pre_row["price"]
        #Only update when condition it's true
        if (match_price < match_price_2) == False: 
            df.at[index, 'triggered'] = result
        matched = False
        start_search = False
    pre_row = row

print(df)
```

### Output

```
          price direction          event  High_cross  movement  triggered
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0   0.00225246      down              0       False     False        No
 1   0.00225506        up    crossing up       False     False        No
 2   0.00225347        up              0       False     False        No
 3   0.00225345        up              0       False     False        No
 4   0.00225613        up              0        True  movement        No
 5   0.00225506        up              0        True      True        No
 6   0.00225345        up              0       False  movement        No
 7   0.00225235      down              0       False     False        No
 8   0.00224500      down  crossing down       False     False       Yes
 9   0.00225266      down              0       False     False        No
 10  0.00225246        up    crossing up       False     False        No
 11  0.00225506        up              0       False     False        No
 12  0.00225506      down  crossing down       False     False        No
```

Comment: How would you store the vector of results and update the df["new_column"], because when I do it, it updates also when there is not a `movement` between a `crossing up` and `crossing down`

Comment: I mean, you can store the result of each row in a vector, `array_of_bool = [ ]` , and then `array_of_bool.append(result)`, I didn't because i no understand where the result it should save, so, where?

Comment: I just updated the above example :)! As you can see it updates the column `triggered` when there is an `movement` between a `crossing up` and `crossing down but did not update when there is no `movement` event! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Checkout now, I put the others values as `False` but if needed it's easy to change

Comment: You can see that in the loop if you erase the `break` it will update the column `triggered` next to the second `crossing down` and update the column `triggered`  to `True`, which it should not be the case :s

Comment: Yes in this example above it should be equal to `False` indeed because the first price is bigger than the second price :) does we have to change something to the code then? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188887/discussion-between-blaztix-and-viktor-w).